# How do I make separate secure zones from the same login page in Adobe Business Catalyst?

Tags: javascript, html, business-catalyst

Is there a way in Business Catalyst to make separate secure zones that are all accessed through the same login page? What I would want to try to achieve is to only have one login page which, depending on the login information provided by the customer, would redirect him to his secure zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I used a blank redirect page with some jQuery in it which points to the first of however many secure zones the user has. To get to that redirect page, I had to change the code for the generic secure zone login box by changing the `OID=` and `OTYPE=` attributes. Simply change the `{}` tag after both and input the page id after `OID=` and type in `1` with no quotation marks after `OTYPE=` .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the answer by nvncbl above will work, but I've tried this suggestion found on the Business Catalyst Adobe forum - https://forums.adobe.com/message/5995509#jive-105794934932394866742980 and I can attest that it works.

First setup a page called redirect.html (or your chosen name) and add the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.documentElement.className += " js";</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     document.location.href = jQuery('.zoneName:first a').attr('href');

});

</script>

<div style="display: none;">

     {module_subscriptions}

</div>
```

Publish the page. Go into BC and grab the PageID. To do this open the page in the BC admin. Look at the URL bar you will see: site.com/AdminConsole/#!/Admin/WebPages_Detail.aspx?PageID=123456

Grab the PageID numbers.

Insert a Generic Login form and change the action URL:

action="https://site.worldsecuresystems.com/ZoneProcess.aspx?ZoneID=-1&OID=[page-ID-goes-here]&OTYPE=1">

Example: action="https://site.worldsecuresystems.com/ZoneProcess.aspx?ZoneID=-1&OID=123456&OTYPE=1">

When a person logs into a site it will direct them to the landing page of the first secure zone in the {module_subscriptions}.